# Overwrite a layout file from adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml

How can I overwrite a layout file from admin? I am able to change template files but not layout files. I want to add in head jQuery because right now it is added after prototype and I have problems when merging js. I just want to add in main.xml from adminhtml to load first jQuery. I don't want to change directly in the default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how I missed that on [magento commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates)

It is actually simpler than I thought, just using the right code in config.xml of your module:

```
<admin>
    <design>
        <package>
            <name>default</name>
        </package>
        <theme>
            <default>your_custom_theme_name</default>
        </theme>
    </design>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

After you add the jQuery you should add another js file containing

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This will prevent jQuery from using $.

As both prorotype.js and jQuery are using the $, these two will never work together. One should drop the $.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question. I already have jQuery.noConflict(); and I don't have any issue until I merge js files.

Answer (score 1):

Magento - Override adminhtml template/layout file

Add below code to config.xml file of extension (you created)

```
<stores>
<admin>
    <design>
        <theme>
            <default>default</default>
            <template>rwd</template>
        </theme>
    </design>
</admin>
```

Now create rwd folder under adminhtml/default folder package. app/design/adminhtml/default/rwd and create template and layout file as you want to override.

like we want to override order comment history.phtml file.

```
\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml 

\app\design\adminhtml\default\rwd\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml
```

OR you can also override layout file like.

```
   \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\sales.xml 
   \app\design\adminhtml\default\rwd\layout\sales.xml
```